# Proof by induction

Tags: proof-verification, induction

Prove by induction a result of the form “for all $n ≥ T, 2n < n!$”. Use the best possible value of T.

So I understand for T = 1,2,3 the inequality is wrong but for T = 4 it's True. so our conjecture is $$
n \geq 4 \implies 2n < n!
$$

So inductive step is where I'm struggling.

I started of as but wasn't sure how to carry on. 
$$
(n+1)! = n!\cdot (n+1) \overset{}{>} 2n(n+1)
$$

Comment: Maybe it would help if you wrote out the inductive assumption, and what you're trying to prove, in the inductive step. That way you might not be so "adrift"

Comment: Is $n > 1$?  Is $2n > 2$?  Is $2n(n+1) > 2(n+1)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For all natural numbers $n \geq 4$:
>   $$ 2n < n!$$

*Proof*: (by Induction). Let $P_n$ be the following proposition:
$$P_n: \qquad 2n <n! $$

**Base Case**: If $n = 4$, it follows that $2n=8$ and $n! = 24$, so $2n < n!$. Therefore, we have that $P_4$ holds.

**Inductive Step**: Assume, for the sake of induction, that $P_k$ holds for some arbitrary $k$. Then, we have:
\begin{align*}
2k &< k! \\
2k(k+1) &< (k+1)! \\
2k^2 + 2k &< (k+1)! \\
\end{align*}
Since $k$ is a natural number, $k^2 \geq 1$, so we can state that:
\begin{align*}
2k^2 + 2k &< (k+1)! \\
2 + 2k &< (k+1)! \\
2(k+1) &< (k+1)! \\
\end{align*}

Therefore, we have shown that $P_k \implies P_{k+1}$.

**Conclusion**: We have shown:
$$ P_4 \wedge (P_k \implies P_{k+1})$$
By mathematical induction, we have that $P_n$ holds for all natural numbers $n \geq 4$.

Answer (score 1):

$(n+1)! = (n+1)n! > (n+1)2n > 2(n+1)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $2n < n!$ for $n\geq 4$, then $$(n+1)! > 2n\cdot (n+1) > 2(n+1)$$
because $n>1$.